# De-activation of plugin dependant on another

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am writing a Woocommerce extension plugin and have managed to set it so Woocommerce must be installed and activated under the Wordpress admin pages.

If both Woocommerce and my extension plugin are activated and Woocommerce is de-activated, my plugin stays active.

How do I de-activate my plugin when Woocommerce is also de-activated?

Edit 1.

I have tried this, and other similar attempts. The hook is correct, but for some reason deactivate_plugins() does not deactivate the plugin that I am writing.

```
function custom_plugin() {

    if (is_plugin_active('custom_plugin/custom_plugin.php')){

        deactivate_plugins('custom_plugin/custom_plugin.php');
    }
}
register_deactivation_hook( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', 'custom_plugin');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code your active theme OR custom plugin.

```
function custom_plugin_deactivation( $plugin, $data_value ) {
    if ($plugin=="custom/custom.php")
    {
        deactivate_plugins('woocommerce/woocommerce.php');
    }
}
add_action( 'deactivated_plugin', 'custom_plugin_deactivation', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Woocommerce stays active with the code that you have suggested. I have tried this and similar variants but can't figure this out.